# Getting undefined result when invoked function

Tags: javascript, function, variables, ecmascript-6, scope

When I call function in console log it returns `undefined` value. I am not sure what could be the reason for this.

```
function test() {
    var foo=1;
    {
        let boo=2;
        console.log(boo);
    }
    console.log(foo);
}

console.log(test());
```

Output

```
2
1
undefined
```

Comment: Because your function returns nothing and you're logging the function call.

Comment: This is expected behavior, as stated by others, your function does not return anything, yet you are calling it like you are expecting it to.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Is it coming because of hoisting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to log the output/return value of your test() function.
Since nothing is returned, it will log it out as undefined.

return something and you will see it log something out:

```js
    function test() {
        var foo=1;
        {
            let boo=2;
            console.log(boo);
        }
        console.log(foo);
        return "you should return something here"
    }
    
    console.log(test());
```

Comment: Can i use void if return nothing?

Comment: You can (return null), but console still log it out as "null".